# напечатать текущую дату — номер дня года

Tags: python

Как напечатать текущую дату в формате номера дня года вида 1...365?

Comment: Ну и с какой стати такие вопросы минусуются и закрываются??

Comment: @Qwertiy: отсутствие понимания целей и задач Stack Overflow. В тему: [Следует ли закрывать все вопросы, в которых нет кода?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3892/23044)

Comment: @jfs, этот вопрос на 100% соответствует целям и задачам SO.

Comment: @Qwertiy: верно. Комментарий был ответ на вопрос: "почему закрывают", потому что не понимают целей Stack Overflow. Подробней по ссылке.

Comment: @Qwertiy, "...почему минусуются..." - потому, что ответ лежит прямо в документации.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, это не причина.

Answer (score 7):

[Документация для strftime формата](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) говорит что `'%j'` выводит день года, дополненный нулями до 3 знаков:

```
import datetime as DT

today = DT.date.today()  # текущая дата
print(f"{today:%j}")  # номер дня в году с 1
# -> 038
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime
print(datetime.date.today().strftime("%j"))
```